# Why is /var/lib/dpkg/status missing on a BitBake-generated OS?

Tags: apt, yocto, dpkg, bitbake, openembedded

I have installed `apt` onto a system built by BitBake by adding the `apt` package to the `IMAGE_INSTALL` variable in my recipe.

`apt-get` and `apt-cache` now execute on the built system, but if I try to do anything useful with them (such as `apt-get update` or `apt-cache search`), I get the following error:

```
E: Could not open file /var/lib/dpkg/status - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened
```

After some preliminary searching, I found this exchange on the Yocto Project mailing list:

> > Hi,
> >
> > I have some requirement with `apt-get` in yocto genearted rootfs.
> >
> > I built the yocto source code with enabling the `apt` package.
> >
> > But after booting the image on my machine and run the "`apt-get`" command for installing some package it gives the following error.
> >
> > `Could not open the file /var/lib/dpkg/status open(2: no such a file or directory).`
> >
> > The package lists or status files could not be parsed or opened.
>
> This error is because you need to add `package-management` to `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES` in `local.conf`,
>
> `PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_deb"`
> `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "debug-tweaks package-management"`

I've added `package-management` but don't see any different output.

After a `touch /var/lib/dpkg/status`, `apt-get update` returns the following:

```
Reading package lists...Done
```

How can I get `apt` into a functioning state through the use of BitBake metadata?

Comment: And did you set PACKAGE_CLASSES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a similar [thread](https://community.freescale.com/thread/325384) from the NXP website.

You would need to set up your own web server and provide all those packages and add the server URL to the source list. [SourceList](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList)

In addition, you have to update the package manifest by running `bitbake package-index` and add `PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= " package_deb"` to conf/local.conf

I have successfully set up OPKG before.  The steps are similar, you can find it [here](http://wiki.hioproject.org/index.php?title=Yocto:_Opkg_Package_Management_System_Set_Up)